# Storing Kafka Offsets in S3 instead of topic in distributed mode

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

As Debezium Mongo Source Connector reads the change stream and captures the mutation , and stores the information about the position till where it has read in `/tmp/connect.offsets` or `connect-offsets` topic in standalone and distributed mode respectively.

The stored information is binary converted HashMap containing connector-name and some cluster info as a key and resumeToken as value , in the following form

(This is the info obtained on converting binary)
`Key:` 
`["debezium-mongo-source-in",{"rs":"Cluster0-shard-0","server_id":"xdebezium"}]`

`Value: {"sec":1683566267,"ord":19,"transaction_id":null,"resume_token":"8264592EBB000000132B022C0100296E5A10040586028B20A1484161EAA0F46645F696400646448B6E3D382E3B80004"}`

so , as written above , this info gets stored in connect-offsets topic ,
is there a way to store these offsets in external data-store such as S3 ? (preferred if ,with help of some configuration change)

I checked if there is some way via configuration change , but found its not possible , as in Kafka Connect Code ,
In ConnectStandalone mode , FileOffsetBackingStore is used [GithubLink](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/b40a7fc037bb1543c3355fad9c71570f770f5177/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/cli/ConnectStandalone.java#LL95C9-L96C133) and

In case of ConnectDistributed mode , KafkaOffsetBackingStore is used [GithubLink](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/b40a7fc037bb1543c3355fad9c71570f770f5177/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/cli/ConnectDistributed.java#L82) , so its seems like it can't be overridden using configurational change.

So one way seems to modify code , and build jar out of it , but seems not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect Source connectors in distributed mode are required to use the offsets topic for storage.

You could use S3 Sink Connector to write the offsets topic to S3...

But then you have offsets for *that* sink consumer stored in `__consumer_offsets` topic.

Comment: yes I thought of this way as well , it seemed not so clean to me. anyway Thanks for the input.
Another may be trash way , to change in the connector and do adding that offset to s3 as the sideEffect in the connector itself.

Comment: Sure, Kafka is open source, so go ahead and fork it